# webdriver-manager update failed to download chrome driver and update-config.json

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

When I clean webdriver-manager and update, it is unable to download chrome driver and update-config.json. Later on when I start protractor it is complaining couldn't find update-config.json.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "webdrivermanager:update": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone=3.4.0 --ignore_ssl",
    "webdrivermanager:clean": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager clean",
    "install": "npm run webdrivermanager:clean && npm run webdrivermanager:update"
  }
```

**protractor.conf.js**

```
seleniumServerJar: '../../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar',
    multiCapabilities: [
        {browserName: 'chrome'}
        //specify if any other browser
    ],
    directConnect: true,
```

> Now when I do npm install, I can not see chrome driver and
>   update-config.json at
>   node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
>   location

[image]

**webdriver-manager update log**

```
> node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.standalon
e=3.4.0 --ignore_ssl
[09:58:34] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate

(node:10944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (reje
ction id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'ListBucketResult' of undefined
[09:58:34] I/downloader - curl -o C:\..\..\node_mo
dules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium/selenium-server-standal
one-3.4.0.jar https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/selenium-serve
r-standalone-3.4.0.jar
[09:58:35] I/downloader - curl -o C:\..\..\node_mo
dules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium/geckodriver-v0.16.1.zip
 https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.16.1/geckodriver-v0
.16.1-win64.zip
[09:58:36] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.16.1.zip
```

In my log also chrome driver is not downloading anymore. For this reason I can not start my protractor as update-config.json is not available. Any idea would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was very weird. I did everything nothing helped. Actual reason was my organization blocked the chrome driver api site. `chrome-response.xml` is the main clue that is showing access denied message so, I came to know actual reason.

I requested to @cnishina to thrown an actual error message if chrome driver website is not reached.

Answer (score 0):

During a previous `update` call, the xml response was cancelled before the file could be created. There are two options (features to fix this are not complete yet):

1. delete the `chrome-response.xml` and then call `update` again
2. wait an hour and make an `update` request again. The last modified time will invalidate that file and it will make a request and will replace the `chrome-response.xml`.

Comment: The reason was somehow my organization blocked the google chrome driver api site. If there is appropriate log message that would be nice. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm... I will check if I throw actual errors if the website is not reached. I will take a look at it soon. Your StackOverflow question spawned a few changes to fix some of the issues I listed in my response.

Answer (score 0):

On my end, if my webdriver-manager instance was closed.
I am required to delete npm and npm-cache folders from roaming and reinstall protractor again.
Right after installing protractor, webdriver-manager update needs to be executed immediately.
If an error appears, make sure to run node.js cmd as an admin.
With these steps, I was able to download drivers properly.

Comment: The reason was somehow my organization blocked the google chrome driver api site.  So it couldn't download the google driver...

Comment: This is interesting. Do you know why you need to remove the node module? That's weird.

Comment: my company is also blocking google chrome, just make sure that you've done the steps above and that you setup the proxy properly (including npm proxy).

@cnishina, only after a fresh installation that webdriver will update properly on my end.