# Protractor:Chrome driver download failed because api blocked by my company

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, protractor

I want to download chrome and run full testing on a server.
I am running E2E testing on a server but during this command

> npm install
> webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl --version.chrome =112.1223.39

the command is not able to download chrome browser any help how can i download chrome?
I found out my company not allow public access apis

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741541/webdriver-manager-update-failed-to-download-chrome-driver-and-update-config-json